# mail takes too much time to send emails, why?

Tags: sendmail

I'm sending emails by PHP method `mail()` and every time it takes 20-40 seconds to produce a result. Looks like my server (`sendmail`) is configured to synchronous sending of emails. That's why the PHP script has to wait..

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendmail does not do synchronous sending of emails.  The most common problem is delays in doing DNS lookups.  It may also be delays in doing verification of some of the data you are supplying.  Sendmail is likely verifying: the address provided in the HELO message,  the email address the mail is supposed to be coming from, or the destination address.  Try running an email session using telnet from your web server.  You should see where the delay is quickly.